# Is there a way to find the minimum complete subgraph in a complete graph?

Tags: math, graph-theory

Given a undirected weighted complete graph `G=(V,E)` of `N` vertices, I want to know that if finding the smallest complete subgraph (with minimum edge weights sum) with `M` vertices (`M <= N`) is NP-hard or not.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is NP-hard, because the decision form of the [clique problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem) can be reduced to it.

The decision form of the clique problem asks, given an undirected graph and an integer k, whether there is a complete subgraph with k vertices. This problem is NP-hard. Given an instance of this problem, construct a complete weighted graph on the same number of vertices by assigning a weight of 1 to any edge present in the original graph, and a weight of 2 to any edge not present in the original graph. Then a minimum-weight complete subgraph will have every edge weight equal to 1 if and only if there is a complete subgraph of size k in the original graph.

Comment: Maybe I didn't make it clear in the question. The original graph is a complete graph already, so every subgraph is complete. The problem now is to find  the minimum subgraph.

Comment: @FunnyBunnyleaksmemory Yes, I know, that was already clear in your question. But if you start with an instance of the clique problem then you do not in general have a complete graph already.

Comment: Why would I start with an instance of the clique problem?

Comment: To show that the clique problem can be reduced to your problem, as stated in the first sentence of my answer. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduction_(complexity)

Comment: The idea is that if your problem could be solved in polynomial time, then we could use that solution to solve the clique decision problem in polynomial time.